# Android.Views.InflateException : Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class toolbar

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.android

I am having a problem with this code. When I run it in kitkat, it prompts an unhandled exception

Android.Views.InflateException : Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class toolbar

BTW: I also used

< android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar >

...

< / android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar >

as suggested in other questions but it's still the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Error came from this toolbar-->

    <Toolbar 
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@color/lime"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:elevation="6dp">
        <TextView
            android:text="BranchName"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginRight="155dp"
            android:id="@+id/branchName"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Logout"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

it is included from other .axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:background="#fafafa"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <!--Toolbar was called from here by include-->

        <include 
            layout="@layout/ToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/olive"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/backB"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@color/olive"
                android:id="@+id/backButton"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp">
                <TextView
                    android:text="My Orders"
                    android:textAppearance="?                                                                                                          android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--Other codes are not related anymore to the issue-->

    </LinearLayout>
```

I researched a lot but I think other issues regarding InflateException are not related to my issue.
What should I fix here?

Comment: Please update whole logcat for better analysis.

Comment: I guess it could be because of activity you extended. try http://stackoverflow.com/a/33727136/6212404

Answer (score 10):

After lots of testings, I made it :D
Thanks to
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-tips-hello-appcompatactivity-goodbye-actionbaractivity/

here are my changes

I added nuget xamarin.android.support.v7.appCompat and it's dependencies. (since xamarin don't have gradle)

*in activity.cs:

-using Android.Support.V7.App;

-from public class OrdersActivity : Activity

-to public class OrdersActivity : AppCompatActivity

*in style.xml

-from style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar"

-to style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

*in ToolbarLayout.axml

-from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Toolbar
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@color/lime"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:elevation="6dp">

      ...
   
  </Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

-to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--I change it back to android.support.v7.widget-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@color/lime"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:elevation="6dp">

      ...
   
  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```